# missing yearmon labels using ggplot scale_x_yearmon

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, zoo

I have grouped some data by month and year, converted to yearmon using zoo and am now plotting it in ggplot. Does anyone know why one of the ticklabels are missing and there is one for 2018-07, when there is no data for that month?

Example data:

```
df <-  data.frame(dates = c("2019-01", "2019-02", "2018-08", "2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-11", "2018-12"), values= c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6))
df$dates <- as.yearmon(df$dates)

ggplot(df, aes(x = dates, y = values)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +      
  theme_light() +
  xlab('Month') +
  ylab('values')+ 
  scale_x_yearmon(format="%Y %m")
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `scale_x_yearmon` was meant for xy plots as it calls `scale_x_continuous` but we can just call `scale_x_continuous` ourselves like this (only the line marked ## is changed):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = dates, y = values)) + 
 geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +      
 theme_light() +
 xlab('Month') +
 ylab('values')+ 
 scale_x_continuous(breaks=as.numeric(df$dates), labels=format(df$dates,"%Y %m")) ##
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I think it's an issue with plotting `zoo` objects. Use the standard `Date` class and specify the date label in ggplot. You'll need to add the day into the character string for your `dates` column. Then you can use `scale_x_date` and specify the `date_labels`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <-  data.frame(dates = c("2019-01", "2019-02", "2018-08", "2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-11", "2018-12"), values= c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)) %>% 
  arrange(dates) %>% 
  mutate(dates = as.Date(paste0(dates, "-01")))


ggplot(df, aes(x = dates, y = values)) + 
geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
scale_x_date(date_breaks="1 month", date_labels="%Y %m") +
theme_light() +
xlab('Month') +
ylab('values')
```

[image: result plot]

Comment: It is not an issue with plotting zoo objects. There are no zoo objects in this problem.

Comment: Sorry I meant yearmon class. I don’t know what’s causing the problem but the solution above provides the desired output