# How to display the December in xaxis when using autoplot and yearmon

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot yearmon ts data using autoplot, but it doesn't show the December in xaxis, how to fix it?

```
library(zoo)
library(xts)
tmp <- ts(1:10, start=c(2018,8), frequency = 12)
autoplot(as.xts(tmp)) +
  scale_x_yearmon()
```

[image]

Comment: Using `scale_x_yearmon(n = 12)` seems to achieve this - although on my machine, it generates a mysterious additional tick mark outside and to the left of the x axis. I believe this is because the scale is based on year quarters.

Comment: @Hardley Sir, is this a bug?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591625/missing-yearmon-labels-using-ggplot-scale-x-yearmon/54592173#54592173

Comment: @42 is the question duplicated? I definately know how to plot with ggplot2 by converting ts data to a dataframe, what I wanted is to address how to polt ts data correctly in autoplot.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck  Thanks. I know how to plot with ggplot2 by converting ts data to a dataframe, what I wanted is to address how to polt ts data correctly in autoplot.

Comment: The point of the link is to use `scale_x_continuous` instead of `scale_x_yearmon` if the latter does not give the desired result.  Also if you are using Windows be sure you have expanded the plot area since that can make a difference in the appearance.  If you haven't done that it might be that your code already gives the desired result.

Comment: Fixed. ` autoplot(as.xts(tmp)) +  scale_x_yearmon(breaks=index(as.xts(tmp)), labels=index(as.xts(tmp)))`